# Securing bucket- and resource access in Amazon Web Services S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I have an upload form on my website where each logged on user can upload videos. When uploading videos I generate a new folder in the bucket with a random name, and in this folder all the uploaded videos are placed. I want to, somehow, restrict the access to the uploaded files only to the user who uploaded the video. What are the suggested approaches?

I read that you can programatically create IAM (AWS Identity and Access Management) users:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_create.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/IAM.html#createUser-property

The ‘Introduction to AWS IAM’-video mention that you can restrict access to AWS resources to each and every IAM user:

- https://aws.amazon.com/iam/

Is this a good approach?

My idea of an approach:

- Only logged on users will be able to upload. They have an account in our database
- We need to connect a database user to an IAM identify somehow. Store something in the database?
- When a user tries to upload a video file, check if the user record in the database has an IAM identity, if not create one
- Somehow store which AWS S3 resources a user has access to. What is the best way to do this?

More questions:

- Is it enough with one bucket on AWS S3 or do I need I need one per person
- Do I actually need to create IAM Users to restrict access, or is it possible in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Cognito Identity Pool is perfect for this scenario. For the authorized role, give it a policy that looks something like this:

```
{
    "Sid": "Access User-Specific Folder",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "s3:PutObject",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET-NAME/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
}
```

This restricts a user to only objects in the folder that has the same name as their unique id in you Identity Pool. This method only uses one bucket.

Any time that you are thinking about programmatically making custom IAM roles for each user or a different bucket for each user, the answer is to use Cognito Identity.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this knowledge.